# Set reactjs input value using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, automation, ui-automation

I want to automate some stuff on site I am using recently a lot. Site is made with `reactjs`.

I have problem with setting element's `value` attribute. This function:

```
function setElementValue(element, value) {
    element.value = value;
    var event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent('input', true, true);
    event.simulated = true;
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

works for most of elements. Lets say I found this element:

```
<textarea class="form-title" placeholder="Title" maxlength="200" ></textarea>
```

I can easly set it's value by:

```
var element = document.GetElementsByClassName('form-title')[0];
setElementValue(element, "foo");
```

This is working fine. The problem is with few elements like:

```
<input type="text" step="0.01" min="0" max="9007199254740992" class="form_amount" maxlength="1000" pattern="(\s|\d){0,13}(\.|,)?\d{0,2}" placeholder="Enter amount" value="">
```

For some reason when I use my `setElementValue` function it doesn't work properly. I can see that value has been set, but it seems that `OnChange` wasn't applied (form is being validated, and I am getting error that amount is not specified).

All I have to do now is to manually click on this element, and now I see that it was filled properly (error message is gone).

Anyone have any ideas what should I do?

Comment: You use wrong approach. With React you should _**not modify**_ DOM directly. All changes in DOM have to be implemented via `render` calls. Read [this](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)

Comment: @hindmost Site is not mine. I want to automate stuff on that site. How what you've wrote is related to my problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are using react right now ?

Comment: @Treycos yes, I am sure.